# What are local variables in thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

According to Java Concurrency in Practices,

> Each thread has its own program counter, stack, and local variables.

I have confusion with the statement "local variables". What do the local variables mean here? Does it mean local copy of shared variable in thread, for example if two threads read one global variable asynchronously, each thread holds a copy of that variable in its code execution / path?

Or is it referring to the variables which are declared and created explicitly inside threads and which are not shared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local variables are just local-scoped variables. See [JLS 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) for more info and examples.

In the following method

```
void method(String param1, int param2) {
    String concat = param1 + param2;
    if(concat.length() > 2) {
        int length = concat.length();
        System.out.println("concat is " + length + " character long");
    }
}
```

Local variables include method arguments (`param1`, `param2`), variables declared in the method (`concat`, `length`)

For your question, it's the variables whose life does not extend beyond the execution of the method.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It really makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider when threads are started - eg :

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private String name;

    public void kickOff() {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread();
        thread1.start();
        Thread thread2 = new Thread();
        thread2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        Person person = findSomeRandomPerson();
        printPerson(person);
    }

    public void printPerson(Person person) {
        String desc = person.toString();
        doSomething(desc);

        // This is bad - the threads can interfere
        this.name = "Hello " + desc;
        doMore(this.name)            
    }
}
```

So here we have one instance of the MyThread class, with two threads running - both starting from the `run()` method.

What the `local variables` bit means is that the local variables in the `run()` methods (and subsequent calls) won't interfere with eachother across threads (even though they are executed within the context of the same instance of the MyThread class).

For example, if thread1 gets Person fred, and thread2 gets Person bill, thread1's call to `printPerson` is always guaranteed to have `desc` be the description for fred (and likewise `desc` will always be the description for bill in thread2).

EDIT TO ADD:
Further to your question about " if two threads read one global variable asynchronously, each thread holds a copy of that variable"

No, threads do not hold their own copies of objects.  For example consider the `name` instance variable above.

That is an instance variable of MyThread.  As previously stated, both threads are running within the context of the SAME INSTANCE of MyThread.  That means they are both accessing the SAME INSTANCE of name.   That means when one changes 'name', the other will see that change.

The upshot is that setting `this.name` and calling `doMore(this.name)` like this is bad.  For example, the following sequence of actions is perfectly possible :

1. Thread 1 sets this.name to "Hello fred"
2. Thread 2 sets this.name to "Hello bill"
3. Thread 1 calls doMore(this.name)

This will result in thread 1 calling `doMore("Hello bill")` , since the threads are accessing the same object (not their own copy of the object).

Welcome to the wonderful world of race conditions !